# Haskell, parameters of ask

Tags: haskell, monads

Could you help what parameter is getting by `ask` ?
We often can see `ask >>= f`
It means that `ask >>= f = (\k -> f (ask k) k)`
So ask must be able to get k, function from enviroment.
However, in docs it is written: `ask :: m r`.
Where am I wrong ?

Comment: "`ask >>= f = (\k -> f (ask k) k)`" This is wrong.

Comment: so show me please correct equality. I found it here https://www.haskell.org/wiki/df4e1f5471fe2a2Monads_as_containers

Comment: the other answers have to correct equalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `Reader` monad.  Ultimately the best answer is just to study its implementation, which in it simplest version (no monad transformers, no classes) can be defined like this:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }
```

This is a `newtype` declaration, so `Reader r a` is just a "relabeling" (so to speak) of the function type `r -> a`.  `ask` is defined like this:

```
ask :: Reader r r
ask = Reader (\r -> r)
```

Which means that `ask` is a relabeled **identity function**—the function that just returns its own argument.  We can see this if we use the `runReader` operation to feed values to it :

```
ghci> runReader ask 5
5

ghci> runReader ask "Hello world!"
"Hello world!"
```

That doesn't look very useful, but the magic comes from the fact that `Reader` has instances for `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`:

```
instance Functor (Reader r) where
  fmap f (Reader g) =
      -- A `Reader` that applies `f` to the original `Reader`'s results 
      Reader (\r -> f (g r))

instance Applicative (Reader r) where
  pure a = 
      -- A `Reader` that ignores its `r` argument and just produces
      -- a fixed value.
      Reader (\_ -> a)

  Reader ff <*> Reader fa =
      -- A `Reader` that "combines" two `Reader`s by feeding the same 
      -- `r` value to both, and then combining their results 
      Reader (\r -> ff r (fa r))

instance Monad (Reader r) where
  return = pure

  Reader fa >>= k = 
      -- A `Reader` that feeds the same `r` both to the original one
      -- and to the one computed by the `k` function
      Reader (\r -> k (fa r) r)
```

If you study these, you'll notice that what `Reader` is about is *delaying* the point of the program where you apply the wrapper `r -> a` function to an `r`.  Normally, if you have a function of type `r -> a` and you want to get a value of type `a`, you have to feed the function an argument of type `r`.  The `Reader` class instances allow you instead to supply functions that will be used to operate on the `a` ahead of time, and then supply the `r` in the end.

The `ReaderT` type and the `MonadReader` class (which has the `ask :: MonadReader r m => m r` method) are just more advanced versions of this.

Comment: So it should be true that: `ask >>= f = Reader (\r -> f (ask r) r) = Reader (\r -> f(r) r)`

Answer (score 5):

A value of type `m a` where `m` is a Monad, can be thought of as a "monadic action". So `ask` doesn't take any parameters, it's just a value that you can bind (`>>=`) to extract some value from a Reader monad.

Look at the definition of `ask` for `ReaderT` in `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader`:

```
-- | Fetch the value of the environment.
ask :: (Monad m) => ReaderT r m r
ask = ReaderT return
```

`ReaderT` is just a data constructor that contains a value of type `r -> m a`, so `ReaderT return` is a value of type `ReaderT r m r` that contains a function, `return` (of the monad `m`).

In other words, `ask` here is a "monadic action" that extracts the value of stored inside the `Reader`.

```
ask >>= f
```

Which is

```
(ReaderT return) >>= f
```

Using definition of `>>=` for Reader, we get:

```
ReaderT $ \ r -> do
    a <- runReaderT (ReaderT return) r
    runReaderT (f a) r
```

Which reduces to

```
ReaderT $ \ r -> do
    a <- return r
    runReaderT (f a) r
```

Or

```
ReaderT $ \r -> runReaderT (f r) r
```

So, it passes the stored value along to decide the next action and also passes the value so the next actions can read it as it was before.

(If this wasn't clear, look for a Reader tutorial maybe)

Comment: What does mean r in \r ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Are you asking what the syntax `\r -> ...` means or are you asking what the `r` parameter represents?

Comment: what represents. I know this syntax, just lambda :)